# Print an infinite sequence using generator

Tags: python, generator, infinite-sequence

I'm trying to create a generator that prints out a specified infinite sequence. Currently, I have the following code:

```
def numGen():
for i in range(1,13):
    yield i
```

Which then gives me:

```
>>> y = numGen()
>>> y
<generator object numGen at 0x7f6b88d22570>
>>> y.__next__()
1
...
>>> y.__next__()
12
>>> y.__next__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> StopIteration
```

I'm not sure what would need to be changed in order for it to reset and then print out 1, 2, 3, ..., 11, 12, 1, 2, 3,... I've tried adding the line "i += 1" after the yield line, but it would then print out 14 which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core problem with the shown generator is it *only* loops the sequence once - and then it stops. A simple change would be to wrap it in an outer `while True`, eg.:

```
def numGenForever():
    while True:
        for i in range(1,13):
           yield i
```

This would then be "infinite" because it would restart the sequence iteration after each previous completion.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I didn't think to incorporate both the while and the for loop together. Previous iterations of my code had either a "i = range(1,13), while True: yield i" or just the "While True: yield i" with the function taking in a parameter "num". Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @BrxttB You're welcome. Take time to understand the different ways of accomplishing this task. I focused on showing the issue; not necessarily the 'best' or 'most Pythonic' way.

Comment: I will, so far in my class that's pretty much the way my professor had taught us how to use generators. I will/am making the effort to investigate more on using generators

Answer (score 4):

Just cycle it.

```
y = itertools.cycle(numGen())
```

Comment: That did work, however the generator function should be able to infinitely cycle through it. I will add itertools to my toolbox for other projects though!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3.3 or later, you can use `yield from`, which yields successive elements from an iterable. You can then put that into an infinite loop - as it is, there's nothing infinite about your function.

```
def numGen():
    while 1:
        yield from range(1,13)
```

When it finishes yielding the numbers from 1 to 12, the loop will start the sequence over again.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 3.4, and I didn't know there was a "yield from", but that also helps as well, thank you! I knew it wasn't infinite, but I forgot I could nest a While and a for loop together thus making it infinite.